# .htaccess redirect if match pattern else do nothing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have three scenario to satisfy

Scenarios are

1. Need to redirect if `www.example.com` then to `www.example.com/a-a`
2. Need to redirect if `www.example.com/pages` then to `www.example.com/a-a/pages`
3. Need not to redirect if `www.example.com/b-b` then go as it is `www.example.com/b-b`
4. Need not to redirect if `www.example.com/b-b/pages` then go as it is `www.example.com/b-b/pages`

My code is satisfying the first two scenarios and forcing always the same. I couldn't bring the not condition.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a-a(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a-a/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/b-b(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  [L,R=301]  # do nothing here and not to do the previous condition
```

Second condition is forcing always to `www.example.com/a-a/b-b`  I do not want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second rule isn't actually doing anything since a request for `/b-b` is caught by the first rule. (The second rule is invalid anyway since you are missing the *substitution* string it would result in an internal rewrite to `[L,R=301]` - which is likely to "break horribly".)

You don't need a second rule. You can create an exception on the first rule with a `RewriteCond` directive, in the same way you created an exception to exclude `/a-a` (and redirecting to itself).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/b-b(/.*)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a-a(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a-a/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the erroneous (301 - **permanent**) redirect to `/a-a/b-b` will have been cached. To avoid caching issues test with 302 (temporary) redirects.

Comment: Perfect Answer, Thanks @MrWhite.  and 302 helped a lot in testing.